# CSS transition between two SEO-friendly webpages

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

### My Goal:

Let's say I've got two webpages `page1` and `page2`. Now, I would like to have an animation (using css transition) to transform `page1` into `page2` or `page2` into `page1` if the user navigates from `page1` to `page2` or from `page2` to `page1` respectively.
Moreover, I would like that search engines can find both pages.

### My Problems / What I've tried:

1. Use actually only one page `page.html` with hashes: `page.html#page1` and `page.html#page2`. For example by listening for a `hashchange` event the transition can be done easily.
2. Use parameters: `page.html?content=page1` and `page.html?content=page2`. A complete reload of the page can be avoided by the `preventDefault` method or `history.pushState`.

As far as I know, in the first solution, search engines are not going to show my pages as separate links. Also, both solutions have the following major problem: What happens if someone writes simply `page.html` into the browser's address field or – even worse – `page.html` appears as a link in search results? I really would like that `page.html` doesn't exist at all, but that seems impossible given the above solutions.

So, the best solution I could think of so far, is having actually two pages `page1.html` and `page2.html` that have both exactly the same content (that is, the content of both pages combined). E.g. in `page1.html` the content of `page2` would have property `display: none`. Now, when a user navigates from `page1` to `page2`, I use `history.pushState` to set the new URL. While I believe this should in principle work, I'm concerned about having two identical pages or hiding large amounts of a page using `display: none` as both is supposed to be bad for SEO.

Any answer that addresses at least part of my problem is very welcome! Maybe there is a way to at least prevent search engines from finding `page.html` in my second solution? Or maybe there is a solution I'm completely unaware of?

Comment: You can prevent search engines from indexing a certain page by adding `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` to the head tag in your HTML.

Comment: @code But if I would include that in my `page.html` won't it also apply to the pages `page.html?content=page1/2` which should be indexed?

Comment: I don’t fully understand what you’re saying, but only the page you add that code to will be affected. I don’t really see any reason to disable SEO though in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `history.pushState` way is fine. Once a user visits page *a*, preload page *b* with JavaScript, and you can apply your CSS transitions that way. You could do something like:

```js
(async () => {
  const page2 = await fetch("/page2.html");
  const text = page2.text();
  // dummy event listener and selector
  document.querySelector('a[href="/page2.html"]').addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // apply CSS transitions by adding classes or whatever
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = text;
    history.pushState(null, null, "/page2.html");
  });
})();
```

This way you don't have to change any of your HTML or CSS and no SEO will be affected. This can also improve your UX by cutting off load times to other pages, kind of like what React Router or NextJS does.